# Can I use RunLoop for realtime object observing in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, runloop, weak

I have a Process object (is kind of Model). Inside a process, I have an array of tuples

```swift
var listeners: [(WeakContainer<AnyObject>, (S) -> ())]
```

`WeakContainer` handles a weak ref inside. I need to remove an element from the `listeners` array when Conainer's value becomes nil. My code looks like this:

```swift
class Process<S> {
    
    typealias Handler = (S) -> ()
    typealias Listener = (container: Weak<AnyObject>, handler: StateHandler)
    
    var listeners: [Listener] = []
    private let runLoop = RunLoop()
    
    init() {
        runLoop.run(mode: .default, before: .now)
        runLoop.perform { [weak self] in
            self?.state.listeners.removeAll {
                $0.container.value == nil
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Is it correct usage of RunLoop for my targets or not? Why?
I will be grateful if you propose a more suitable alternative for my case (tracking for the object becomes nil).

Comment: Do you need a collection with weak references to object which are removed from collection when deallocated?

Comment: How about a NSHashTable with weak keys being your objects and values being your StateHandler function(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `NSMapTable` collection which is flexible for configuring with various memory retaining policy.

Here is an example how to store `Handler` object with a weak key object. `Handler` will be retained until key exist, and the pair will be removed from the collection on key delete.

```
class Handler<Action> {
    let action: Action
    init(_ action: Action) {
        self.action = action
    }
}

var listeners = NSMapTable<AnyObject, Handler<(S)->Void>> (keyOptions: [.weakMemory, .objectPointerPersonality],
                                                           valueOptions: .strongMemory)
```